# Numpy reverse keras to_categorical

Tags: numpy, keras

In keras I have used `to_categorical` to convert by binary nx1 vector y to a nx2 matrix where the first columns is 1 if y=1 and the second column is y=0. How do I reverse this action using numpy?

Comment: You can use `argmax`

Comment: np.argmax(a, axis = 1)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Simple.

```
numpy.argmax(a, axis=None, out=None)
```

This returns the indices of the maximum values along an axis.

Answer (score 13):

Adding to MazeRunner09's answer. If you used to_categorical from keras, you will have a list and can use a list comprehension over the entire one-hot encoded list:

```
y_classes = [np.argmax(y, axis=None, out=None) for y in y_test]
```

Answer (score 11):

No need to do list comprehension. Simply

```py
numpy.argmax(a, axis=1)
```

will find argmax in each row for all rows

Comment: This should be the answer.

Answer (score 3):

This is a complete example of how to reverse labels in tensorflow keras:

```
label = [0,1,1,0]
label = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(label)
print(label) #output: label = [[1,0],[0,1],[0,1],[1,0]]
label = tf.math.argmax(label, axis=1)
print(label) #output back to [0,1,1,0]
```